# Best Way to popBackStack in three fragment in single activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Problem i am getting is the,webservice is calling second time onCreateView when popbackstack from other fragment.

Comment: Is there any problem ?

Comment: Yes I have a list fragment and when i am popback stack then there is problem in listview items

Comment: This is because of your configuration. The answer of mine should solve your main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally recommend you to check [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) before you build them.

If you've managed to communicate with your fragments. Then you can use this simple method.

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment frag, boolean saveInBackstack) {
    String backStateName = ((Object) frag).getClass().getName();

    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, frag, backStateName);

            if (saveInBackstack) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: addToBackTack " + backStateName);
                transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: NO addToBackTack");
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to commit fragment, could be activity as been killed in
    }
}
```